# How to output text to a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a palindrom WPF program, which test if the word is a palindrome.
So I want the user to type whatever he wants.

I've seen on stackoverflow someone had a similar problem, and he used

```
OutputText.Text = (word + Environment.NewLine);
```

But that didn't help me.

```
private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        InputText.Text += s.ToString();
    }
}

private void OutputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var word in InputText.Text.ToString())
        {
            OutputText.Text = word.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I should be able to input the whatever I want and to output the word if it's palindrome. I know I need a method but for now I want exact same input as output.

E.g.

Input: I have radar

Output: I have radar

Comment: Why the `while (true)`?

Comment: So the user can type text always, I was thinking making a program while user is typing the program is already checking if its a palindrome

Comment: Why are you reading from the console?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm new at WPF. Until week ago I was programming using the console only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why *infinite loops* (`while (true) {...}`) and `Consoles`? Something like this:

```
//TODO: your routine which tests for palindrome
private static bool IsPalindrome(string value) 
{
    ...
}

private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // This event handler runs when user changes text in InputText
    // i.e. input anything into InputText 
    // We should:

    // 1. Obtain user input
    string word = InputText.Text;

    // 2. Check for being palindrome
    bool isPalindrome = IsPalindrome(word); 

    // 3. Output results into OutputText
    OutputText.Text = word + (isPalindrome ? " is a palindrome" : " is NOT a palindrome");
}
```

Please, note, that we don't want any `OutputText_TextChanged` (what shall we do if `OutputText` `Text` has been changed?)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're using WPF, you should also think about using [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).
This is a programming paradigm, which encapsulates the view from the codebehind. Essentially the view (what you see) doesn't know where it's data comes from.

This is what WPF's [data bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) are for.

Let's say you have two text boxes, where the code from one should fill the other.

There are your two TextBoxes.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyFirstTextBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{DynamicResource MyVM}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MySecondTextBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{DynamicResource MyVM}" />
```

In your window resources, you have defined an object which is your view model:

```
<Window.Resources >
    <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="MyVM" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Your view model could then look something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) { 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new OnPropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); 
    }

    private string textBox1Text;

    public string MyFirstTextBox {
        get => textBox1Text;
        set {
            textBox1Text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyFirstTextBox));
            MySecondTextBox = value; // Set value of second text box
        }
    }

    private string textBox2Text;

    public string MySecondTextBox {
        get => textBox2Text;
        set {
            textBox2Text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySecondTextBox));
        }
    }

}
```

Now you'd have a very basic MVVM implementation, which should help you further.

If you have no interest in using MVVM, then you can continue using events.

In your codebehind:

```
private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => OutputText.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;

private void OutputText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => Debug.WriteLine("Whoo! My text changed to {0}", (sender as TextBox).Text);
```

**EDIT: Added last stretch of code to code tags.**
Also edit: Sorry if I made a mistake in the code, this was off the top of my head during lunch break.

Comment: Ty MVVM is my next step